# Upload an image file with JSON Format

Tags: python, json, rest, mlflow

I am trying to build a machine learning algorithm an deploy it with REST API. While I am doing this I got some error like "MALFORMED_REQUEST", "message": "Failed to parse input from JSON. Ensure that input is a valid JSON formatted string.". In below you can see my code. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
import json
import requests
import base64

#data = 'cat_Test2.jpg'


with open('./Dataset/test2/cat_Test2.jpg', mode='rb') as file:
    img = file.read()
data = base64.encodebytes(img).decode('utf-8')

#print(json.dumps(data))
#print(data)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
request_uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/invocations'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        response = requests.post(request_uri, data=data, headers=headers)
        print(response.content)
        print('done!!!')
    except Exception as ex:
        raise (ex)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MLflow model server accepts as input either JSON (pandas split-orient format) or CSV.
https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#deploy-mlflow-models

You will need to convert your image into one of those two formats. Example:
https://github.com/amesar/mlflow-examples/tree/master/python/keras_tf_mnist#score-mnist-png-file

Comment: Well, thank you sir I am newbie at machine learning and mlflow. It becomes more and more tidious to me. Those links would be very useful for me

Answer (score 1):

Just because you have converted your image into a (base64 encoded) string, does not mean it's valid JSON now.

I see you've already used `print(json.dumps(data))` in your code, and you should have noticed the wrapping double quotes, compared to just `print(data)`.

Example:

```
import json

s = "abc"
print(s)
print(json.dumps(s))
```

Output:

```
abc
"abc"
```

Only after the quotes are added, the string is valid JSON.

This means that

```
response = requests.post(request_uri, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

should do the job.

---

For completeness, look at this case of loading a string vs loading a JSON string:

```
import json
s = 'abc'
json.loads(s)
```

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

```
import json
s = '"abc"'
print(json.loads(s))
```

> abc